# Terminology: complete m-ary tree

Tags: data-structures, tree

I'm new to data structures, and had a question on terminology.

Is there a standard term for an **m-ary tree** which is maximally space efficient. It must be completely filled on every level except for the last level. However, if the last level is not complete, then all nodes of the tree must be "as far left as possible"?

It is called **complete m-ary tree** on Wiki, but the term has completely different meanings in the Introduction to Algorithms and Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications.

complete m-ary tree on these two books means **perfect m-ary tree** on wiki.

*Introduction to Algorithms*:

> A complete k-ary tree is a k-ary tree in which all leaves have the same depth and all internal nodes have degree k.

*Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications*:

> A complete m-ary tree is a full m-ary tree in which every leaf is at the same level.

[m-ary tree - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-ary_tree)

[Introduction to Algorithms, 4th Edition](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-algorithms-fourth-edition), Appendix B.5 Tree

[Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications, 8th Edtion](https://www.mheducation.com/highered/product/discrete-mathematics-applications-rosen/M9781259676512.html), Chapter 11 Tree, Section 11.1 Introduction to Trees, Exercises 27,28

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are indeed different, conflicting terminologies. This is briefly touched on in the [Wikipedia article on binary trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Types_of_binary_trees). It starts out with the first definition:

> A **complete** binary tree is a binary tree in which every level, *except possibly the last*, is completely filled, and all nodes in the last level are as far left as possible. It can have between 1 and 2<sup>ℎ</sup> nodes at the last level ℎ. A perfect tree is therefore always **complete** but a complete tree is not necessarily **perfect**. An alternative definition is a perfect tree whose rightmost leaves (perhaps all) have been removed.

But then continues:

> Some authors use the term **complete** to refer instead to a **perfect** binary tree as defined above, in which case they call this type of tree (with a possibly not filled last level) an **almost complete** binary tree or **nearly complete** binary tree.

So, no, apparently there is no complete consensus on a standard terminology, and one should be careful to check what an author means when they use the term *complete* in this context.